# how to perform an operation similar to group by on the first index of a multi indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The code to generate a sample dataframe is as follows

```
fruits=pd.DataFrame()
fruits['month']=['jan','feb','feb','march','jan','april','april','june','march','march','june','april']
fruits['fruit']=['apple','orange','pear','orange','apple','pear','cherry','pear','orange','cherry','apple','cherry']
fruits['price']=[30,20,40,25,30 ,45,60,45,25,55,37,60]

ind=(fruits.index)
fruits_grp = fruits.set_index(['month', ind],drop=False)
```

The output dataframe should look something like this:

```
fruits_new1=pd.DataFrame()
fruits_new1['month']=['jan','jan','feb','feb','march','march','march','apr','apr','apr','jun','jun']
fruits_new1['fruit']=['apple','apple','orange','pear','orange','orange','cherry','pear','cherry','cherry','pear','apple']
fruits_new1['price']=[30,30,20,40,25,25,55,45,60,60,45,37]
ind1=fruits_new1.index
fruits_grp1 = fruits_new1.set_index(['month', ind1],drop=False)
fruits_grp1
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks to me like more of sorting than groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
d={'Jan': 0, 'Feb': 1, 'Mar': 2, 'Apr': 3, 'May': 4, 'Jun': 5, 'Jul': 6, 'Aug': 7, 'Sep': 8, 'Oct': 9, 'Nov': 10, 'Dec': 11}

idx=fruits_grp['month'].str.title().str[:3].map(d).sort_values().index
fruits_grp=fruits_grp.reindex(idx)
fruits_grp['s']=list(range(len(fruits_grp)))
fruits_grp=fruits_grp.set_index('s',append=True).droplevel(1).rename_axis(index=['month',None])
```

**Update:**

sample dataframe:

```
fruits=pd.DataFrame()
fruits['month']=[1,2,2,3,1,4,4,6,3,3,6,4]
fruits['fruit']=['apple','orange','pear','orange','apple','pear','cherry','pear','orange','cherry','apple','cherry']
fruits['price']=[30,20,40,25,30 ,45,60,45,25,55,37,60]

ind=(fruits.index)
fruits_grp = fruits.set_index(['month', ind],drop=False)
```

Then just simply use:

```
idx=fruits_grp['month'].sort_values().index
fruits_grp=fruits_grp.reindex(idx)
fruits_grp['s']=list(range(len(fruits_grp)))
fruits_grp=fruits_grp.set_index('s',append=True).droplevel(1).rename_axis(index=['month',None])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Will this work for other types of columns and not essentially months, for instance football teams,  if I enclose the names of the football teams in the dictionary d.

Comment: Also, the order of the second index is changing, what can i do to preserve the order?

Comment: @MedhaChippa pls wait let me see

Comment: @MedhaChippa updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: KeyError: "None of ['s'] are in the columns"

Comment: @MedhaChippa it is working fine kindly rerun the code from beginning

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This works provided the last two lines are removed, since they happen to throw an error, which happens to be similar to the previous piece of code. Some inconsistencies with the notebook at my end had caused this issue. I apologize for the same.

Comment: can the above be achieved if the months are in the form of integers from 1 to 12 and not strings?

Comment: @MedhaChippa yes

Comment: could you please demonstrate it.

Comment: @MedhaChippa firstly pls tell that which one among the 2 you are following?

Comment: The Second one with the dictionary

Comment: @MedhaChippa updated answer....kindly have a look and if it solves your problem then pls try considering accepting the answer(click on the tick to make it green)...thnx **:)**

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits=pd.DataFrame()
fruits['month']= 
['jan','feb','feb','mar','jan','apr','apr','jun','mar','mar','jun','apr']
fruits['fruit']= 
['apple','orange','pear','orange','apple','pear','cherry','pear','orange',
'cherry','apple','cherry']
fruits['price']=[30,20,40,25,30 ,45,60,45,25,55,37,60]

fruits["month"] = fruits["month"].str.capitalize()
fruits["month"] = pd.to_datetime(fruits.month, format='%b', 
errors='coerce').dt.month
fruits = fruits.sort_values(by="month")

fruits["month"] = pd.to_datetime(fruits['month'], format='%m').dt.strftime('%b')
ind1 = fruits.index
fruits_grp1 = fruits.set_index(['month', ind1],drop=False)
fruits_grp1
print(fruits_grp1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Is there a way of getting the above output without the use of to_datetime(). I'm looking for a generic way that can work for any type of column data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all the answers. I've figured out that the sort_values() can make this happen.

The reproducible code for the same is as follows:

```
fruit_grp_srt=fruits_grp.sort_values(by='month')
```

But this sorts the rows in alphabetical order and not in the original order of the 1st index.

Still looking for a better solution, Thank you

Comment: Try changing the index to `CategoricalIndex` and define your custom order

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485120/7041244)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a simple sorting by `month`. First, you need to eliminate the `month` column (as there is a `month` in the index) followed by a `reset_index`

```py
del fruits_grp['month']
df = fruits_grp.reset_index()
```

Then, it is important to set the months as an ordered categorical datatype, and define the custom order.

```py
df.month = df.month.astype('category')
df.month = df.month.cat.reorder_categories(['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april', 'june'])
```

Now, it is just simply sorting by `month`

```py
df.sort_values(by='month')
```

Output

```
    month   level_1     fruit   price
0   jan     0   apple   30
4   jan     4   apple   30
1   feb     1   orange  20
2   feb     2   pear    40
3   march   3   orange  25
8   march   8   orange  25
9   march   9   cherry  55
5   april   5   pear    45
6   april   6   cherry  60
11  april   11  cherry  60
7   june    7   pear    45
10  june    10  apple   37
```